# Google search result's link not working because of params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, seo

I have a rails application which has hotels section under bookings.

When I search in google for london hotels I get a link which somehow has query string params with old dates for check in & check out.

So when someone clicks that link the request comes with old check-in, check-out dates and therefore gives no results.

I have made some changes so that simply putting */bookings/hotels/united-kingdom/london* will fire proper request with check-in, check-out as today's date and tomorrow's date.

What should I do so that the links in google search results don't take old dates for check-in & check-out ?

For those who want to see actual search results search for - travelibro london hotels in google

Answer (score 0):

use canonical in the page to indicate to Google the preferred url like this

and Google will show that in the results

see more details: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139066?hl=en

Comment: Well it was a minor issue with the code. Now if the search results have old dates I am changing those dates accordingly and am now able to show results.